# Printing the shell find and remove command to screen and log file

Tags: shell

I have a script that finds log files older than x days within a specified directory and removes them.

```
find $LOG_ARCHIVE/* -mtime +$DAYS_TO_KEEP_LOGS -exec rm -f {} \;
```

This is working as expected but I would like to have the option to print the processing to the screen and log file so I know what files (if any) have been deleted. I've tried appending `tee` at the end but have had no success.

```
find $LOG_ARCHIVE/* -mtime +$DAYS_TO_KEEP_LOGS -exec rm -fv {} \; | tee -a $LOG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways the task can be done.

One possibility is to simply run `find` twice:

```
find "$LOG_ARCHIVE" -mtime +"$DAYS_TO_KEEP_LOGS" -print > "$LOG"
find "$LOG_ARCHIVE" -mtime +"$DAYS_TO_KEEP_LOGS" -exec rm -f {} +
```

Another possibility is to use `tee` along with (GNU extensions) `-print0` to `find` and `-0` to `xargs`:

```
find "$LOG_ARCHIVE" -mtime +"$DAYS_TO_KEEP_LOGS" -print0 |
tee "$LOG" |
xargs -0 rm -f
```

With this version, the log file will have null bytes at the end of each file name.  You can arrange to replace those with newlines if you don't mind the possible ambiguity:

```
find "$LOG_ARCHIVE" -mtime +"$DAYS_TO_KEEP_LOGS" -print0 |
tee >(tr '\0' '\n' >"$LOG") |
xargs -0 rm -f
```

This uses Bash (and Korn shell) [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to pass the log file through `tr` to map null bytes `'\0'` to newlines `'\n'`.

Another way of doing it is to write a tiny custom script (call it `remove-log.sh`):

```
printf '%s\n' "$@" >> "$LOG"
rm -f "$@"
```

and then use:

```
find "$LOG_ARCHIVE" -mtime +"$DAYS_TO_KEEP_LOGS" -exec bash remove-log.sh {} +
```

Note that the script needs to see the value of `$LOG`, so that must be exported as an environment variable.  You could avoid that by passing the log name explicitly:

```
logfile="$1"
shift
printf '%s\n' "$@" >> "$logfile"
rm -f "$@"
```

plus:

```
find "$LOG_ARCHIVE" -mtime +"$DAYS_TO_KEEP_LOGS" -exec bash remove-log.sh "$LOG" {} +
```

Note that both of these use `>>` to append because the script might be invoked more than once (though it probably won't be).  The onus is on you to ensure that the log file is empty before you run the `find` command.

Note that I dropped the `/*` from the path argument for `find`; it wasn't really needed.  You might want to add `-type f` to ensure that only files are removed.  The `+` is a feature from the POSIX 2008 specification of [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) which makes `find` act rather like `xargs` without needing to explicitly use `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find $LOG_ARCHIVE/* -mtime +$DAYS_TO_KEEP_LOGS -exec sh -c 'echo {} |tee -a "$LOG"; rm -f {}' \;
```

Try and see if it works.

Comment: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: @algorhythm I guess you missed the trailling backslashed semicolon, or you missed some quotes maybe.

Comment: ahh yes the backslash was cut out. No error now but the files aren't being deleted either

Comment: @algorhythm did you get any outputs? what about the $LOG file?